# android location coordinates retrives 0

Tags: java, android, location, coordinates

i have a problem, about gps coordinates in my android application

to get a coordinates I used GPSTracker service:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    //noinspection MissingPermission
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        //noinspection MissingPermission
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        //noinspection MissingPermission
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            //noinspection MissingPermission
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }
    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }
    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }
    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(Dialog

Interface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to add this coordinates into database, here is an implementation:

```
GPSTracker gpstracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    if (gpstracker.canGetLocation) {
        double locationLng = gpstracker.getLongitude();
        double locationLat = gpstracker.getLatitude();

        databaseReference.child("lng").setValue(locationLng);
        databaseReference.child("lat").setValue(locationLat);
    } else
        gpstracker.showSettingsAlert();
```

but only 23, 24, 25 api working well, under it always retrieve 0((((

when I add a debugger, on this stage I get a 0, I don't know why:

```
`public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }
    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }`
```

Comment: location is null that why you getting 0, default value of double

Comment: Get over with `GPSTracker` now, use `FusedLocationAPI` instead. Here your go... https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 0):

```
GPSTracker gpstracker = new GPSTracker(this);
if (gpstracker.canGetLocation) {
    double locationLng = gpstracker.getLongitude(gpstracker);
    double locationLat = gpstracker.getLatitude(gpstracker);

    databaseReference.child("lng").setValue(locationLng);
    databaseReference.child("lat").setValue(locationLat);
}

//pass GPSTracker
public double getLatitude(GPSTracker gpsTracker){
    Location location = gpsTracker.getLocation();
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}
/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(GPSTracker gpsTracker){
    Location location = gpsTracker.getLocation();
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}`
```